# How to acces android.provider.Telephony class?

Tags: android

It seems that this class is not public, and I have to access TELEPHONY_STATUS variables in this class because I see in android source code that the values can change considering what api version you are using.

Comment: If it's not public then it's not meant to be accessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg11410.html) post from the android-developer mailing list.
`android.provider.Telephony` is part of the Open Source releases, but never included as part of the Official SDK.

You can view it, to understand how the system works, but you can't actually use it in your apps.

As it says in the post,

> No, it *does not* appear in the SDK, and this means
>   you should not try to use it from your applications.